# Generate #ifdef, #endif clause with another macro

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I'm having a problem in a program I'm working on. I'm trying in --help to display which features are compiled in or not. However, there are quite alot of these and the "normal" way is too verbose. E.g.:

```
#ifdef HAVE_FOO
static const bool have_foo = true;
#else
static const bool have_foo = false;
#endif
printf("Support for foo: %s\n", have_foo ? "yes" : "no");
```

Now, since I have to do this basically for every feature, it will be loads of lines, which I do not want.

So I thought I'd write some macros for it:

```
#define _SUPP(X) #ifdef HAVE_##X \
static const bool _##X##_SUPP = true; \
#else \
static const bool _##X##_SUPP = false; \
#endif

#define _PRINTSUPP(var, name, desc) printf("\t%s - %s: %s\n", name, desc, _##var##_SUPP ? "yes" : "no")
```

However, there is an issue here. The macro will be expanded to a single line, and the preprocessor chokes on this. Is there a way to generate a macro with actual newlines inbetween, or is it possible to evaluate an `#ifdef` on a single line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If, instead of not defining `HAVE_FOO`, you define it to `0`, you can do:

```
const struct {
    bool present;
    const char *name;
} features[NFEATURES] = {
    {HAVE_FOO, "foo"},
    {HAVE_BAR, "bar"},
    ...
};

for (size_t i=0; i < NFEATURES; i++)
    if (features[i].present)
        printf(" ... and we've got: %s\n", features[i].name);
```

You'll have to check for `#if HAVE_FOO` instead of `#ifdef HAVE_FOO` then, and your `--help` message may be displayed a bit slower if your number of features runs in the zillions (in which case I'd recommend a different architecture anyway).

Comment: guess your are missing a `[]` in the declaration of `features`, no?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this in C. The usual approach is to *generate* such a header from some textual description in, say, Perl or Python.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a macro to create another preprocessing directive.  All preprocessing directives are recognized before macro expansion begins, so your macro will be interpreted as erroneous C code.